# how to set textParameter as password mode

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

i am working in Cruisecontrol and i am using below code to get input from user

```
<parameters>
        <textParameter>
            <name>Password</name>
            <display>Enter Password</display>
            <description>Enter Password</description>
            <default>password@123</default>
            <required>false</required>
        </textParameter>
    </parameters>
```

but problem is that when i am going to type password in textbox, it's readable.there is any way we can set mode password in textbox.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at [the CruiseControl.NET documentation on parameters](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters) it appears there is no option "out of the box" to encrypt the password prompt.

I believe you could write some custom javascript/DOM stuff in the index.html page to handle this on your own (if you want to get creative).